# Geometry Nodes Animation to After effects

Tags: animation, node-editor, export, geometry

I have a scene with several replicated collections in Geometry Nodes which I want to animate and then export certain placeholders for Solids in After Effects.

What I want to export are instances as empties, which can be used as  Nulls in after effects to attach solid or text to the rendered object. The thing is that instances are not exported as separate empties, but only the geometry objects which has Geometry Nodes modifier on is exported. So I was wondering if there is a way to export GN instances as separate empties, which can be used as place holder in After Effects.

Comment: You need to add more details about your workflow, remember that not everyone use AE in this site, so you need to make clear the way you "export" you scene so someone can help you, the more info, the better. Are you using Cineware or Element 3D or is it that AE already works with 3D natively? what format are you using? or is it a Render that you are referring to?

Comment: although i have never used after effects and have no knowledge about it i doubt that after effects "knows" geometry nodes (because even in Blender it is still under development so it is pretty sure that nobody will "embed" or reuse this in another software). So i think the only way you can use it is to apply the geometry nodes modifier before exporting.

Comment: You need to make the instances real or animate all of them individually to have every empty visible and you also need an addon like in [This video](https://youtu.be/BmfJWkmrf34) but i'm not sure if that still works.

Comment: @Emir Thank you. Will check it out !